# "Resource not accessible by integration" when setting status as organisation

Tags: github, github-integration

I was writing a small integration for github (https://github.com/ligi/kontinuum) which works fine when using with the user that I created it with. Now I wanted to use this integration for an organisation - unfortunately I get the following error when trying to write a status for a commit:

```
{"message":"Resource not accessible by integration","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

Reading the documentation there I do not see why writing a status should not work in this context. I think this might be a bug - posting this here as a first stage to a potential bug-report (anyone knows where to report github integration bugs?) and the search for a workaround.

Comment: Hi @ligi, did you solve this?

Comment: There is one setting that allows other users to install this (make app public). Separately, I've encountered this because the token can usually access 'public' data. If you get a 403, verify that the Github App is installed on the repository